# Element appears to be stale error on webelement.clear()

Tags: selenium, junit

I'm locating an element with HtmlUnitDriver. Element is text field (input).

```
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    username.clear();
    username.sendKeys("myValue");
```

I try to clear its contents with username.clear(). But that gives me

Element appears to be stale. Did you navigate away from the page that contained it?

Makes little sense, because I'm not moving around pages. Anyone know what this is?

Comment: what other actions do you perform after finding `username`

Comment: Been trying to username.sendKeys to input another username

Comment: Please post the entire part of code where you deal with that element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and see if it works:

```
public static WebElement getElementByLocator( By locator ) {
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
  WebElement we = null;
  boolean unfound = true;
  while ( unfound ) {
    try {
        we = driver.findElement( locator );
        unfound = false; // FOUND IT
      } catch ( StaleElementReferenceException e ) {                        
        unfound = true;
        Thread.sleep(4000);
      }     
    } 
  }
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT, 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS );
  return we;
}
```

Then,

```
WebElement username = getElementByLocator( By.id("username") );
username.clear();
username.sendKeys("myValue");
```